# DBIx::Class::ResultSet::count(): DBI Connection failed: DBD::Oracle at /usr/share/perl5/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1249

Tags: perl, oracle11g

I have installed DBIX::Class and DBD::Oracle modules. but getting error below

> DBIx::Class::ResultSet::count(): DBI Connection failed: DBD::Oracle at
>   /usr/share/perl5/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1249.

Could you please help me to get resolved

Above Error throws from the below line in my code

```
my $row = $schema->resultset( 'test' )->search ({cols1 => $arg2, cols2=>$arg1});
if($row->count == 1) //thorws error
```

Comment: You don't think it might be useful to show us the code that generates this error?

Comment: Can you produce a small, self-contained example that we can run to see this error?

Comment: I've edited your question to reformat your code example as code. Please do that yourself in future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message mentions both DBD::Oracle and DBIx::Class, so it looks like you installed those correctly :-)

The important part of the error message is "DBI Connection failed", so I suggest you double-check all of the connection details.

**Update:** In a comment below, you share some code that you say works. If you have some code that works and some code that doesn't work, then you should probably compare the two pieces of code and work out what the differences are. We would be happy to help with that, but you haven't shown us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: if i write test file with below contents works fine. `require DBD::Oracle;

 eval qq{package                     # hide from PAUSE
                DBI::_firesafe;         # just in case
            require DBD::Oracle;      # load the driver
    };

require DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=xxx;service_name=xx;port=xx','xx', 'xx', { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 });
print $dbh;`

Comment: @vedagiri:  Please edit your question to add this information. Code in Stack Overflow comments is (deliberately) unreadable.

Comment: in test file,if i add lines `my $row = $schema->resultset( 'test' )->search ({cols1 => $arg2, cols2=>$arg1}); if($row->count == 1) ` Throws same error

Comment: @vedagiri: Once again, please don't share code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Oracle instant client installation steps few missed. 
Mainly missed step: sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3 > \
      /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"